# React Animation's ReactCSSTransitionGroup and CSSTransitionGroup cannot work as in the sample code

Tags: reactjs, react-animations

I am trying the sample code for React Animation:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html
2. https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-forest-ofzfr?file=/src/App.js

```
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          {items}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

It doesn't think `App` exists in `index.js`. But if the `CSSTransitionGroup` is replaced by some static text, then it works (without any animation effect):

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-dust-j0y57?file=/src/App.js

The same with `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-franklin-j2hhp?file=/src/App.js

How can it work?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `TransitionGroup` and `CSSTransition` instead of `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and `CSSTransitionGroup` . The code looks like below

```
import React from "react";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: ["hello", "world", "click", "me"] };
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
  }

  handleAdd() {
    const newItems = this.state.items.concat([prompt("Enter some text")]);
    this.setState({ items: newItems });
  }

  handleRemove(i) {
    let newItems = this.state.items.slice();
    newItems.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ items: newItems });
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
      <CSSTransition
        key={i}
        classNames="example"
        timeout={{ enter: 500, exit: 300 }}
      >
        <div key={item} onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>
          {item}
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Item</button>
        <TransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          {items}
        </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

styles.css

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
.example-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.example-exit.example-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

you can see here in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bash-i8bjt), check this [doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/Migration.md) for more information about migration from v1 to v2

Comment: You said "You should use TransitionGroup and CSSTransition instead of ReactCSSTransitionGroup and CSSTransitionGroup", but why is that? Isn't that how it is done in the sample code? Somehow I feel it is the new era of programming: do this and it will work, but why and how -- don't know...

Comment: The docs is saying "CSSTransitionGroup is a high-level API based on TransitionGroup and is an easy way to perform CSS transitions and animations when a React component enters or leaves the DOM" and you are saying don't use CSSTransitionGroup but use TransitionGroup

Comment: did you notice if you click on the second or third word to delete it, the fade out word is the last one?

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer: [React's official animation docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) as of 2021 April points to the v1 documentation, but if we try the solution there with the current `react-transition-group`, then it would not work.  The reason is that from v2 forward, to the current v4 release, it is not backward compatible with v1.

Therefore, if we are using it or exploring to use it, go to the docs and immediately skip any info that is related to v1.